# Detriment of gelatin fining on flavor or aroma

Tags: techniques, secondary, clarity, fining, gelatin

Does using gelatin effect aromatics or flavor appreciably?

I was reading this post about [using gelatin](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/518/gelatin-for-clearer-beer).  I have one keg that I use as a cold conditioning vessel (sort of like secondary), and I was going to try experimenting with gelatin for a few beers to see if I liked the results.

Thoughts on the negative, if any, impact of gelatin.

Comment: Have you tried it yet?  Any results?  Also, if you use gelatin and you have any vegetarian or vegan friends, it would be good of you to let them know your beer isn't vegetarian.

Comment: I am still fermenting an american wheat and a belgian wit in my chest freezer which is also my kegorater.   Once they are done I have a German hopped Amber in my "bright tank" keg that I will gelatinize after chilling.  I'll let you know here when its done and ready.

Comment: http://brulosophy.com/2015/01/05/the-gelatin-effect-exbeeriment-results/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no real drawbacks that I know of.

It's odorless, translucent, and very nearly tasteless.  I've used it as a fining agent in my secondary.  It does the job a bit better than a cold crash does to drop fine particulates out of solution.  You can make some nice clear beer with a gelatin fining.

The only time I've had any problem is when I didn't prepare the gelatin properly, per the instructions on the box.  Then I got some gelatin chunks on the bottom of my fermenter.  Not a big deal, but irritating.

Comment: so do you just bloom/proof one package in hot water or what?

Comment: Actually you bloom in cold water, then melt the gelatin in hot water.  I use Knox, just follow the instructions on the package.  As to worries about making beer jello, I wouldn't worry about it, its going to get very diluted in the five gallons of young beer.  I used a half package, opinions on how much to use vary.  I wouldn't use more than one package.

Answer (score 2):

I ran across good advice on another site for using the gelatin when fining the beer.  Presumably just before bottling, but I don't know.  Still reading up on the subject.

The link below is 404-ed. It does have a record in the Wayback Machine:

https://web.archive.org/web/20120204042116/https://byo.com/stories/wizard/article/section/121-mr-wizard/1687-would-fining-with-gelatin-have-an-adverse-effect-on-naturally-conditioned-beer

Comment: Just a quickie update.  Lots of good info on fining in this article, again - from another site. 
--> http://www.byo.com/stories/wizard/article/section/121-mr-wizard/1687-would-fining-with-gelatin-have-an-adverse-effect-on-naturally-conditioned-beer

Answer (score 0):

I usually use just whirlfloc tablets for fining, but I'm also very interested in trying gelatin as it is not consistently clear enough. I was going to try it on my most recent brew but it didn't work out and I went ahead and kegged it without trying the gelatin.

At any rate, I've read quite a few forum posts from people who say it works well, and very few that were unsatisfied with the results. The bit I read that really convinced me was on [Brulosphy](http://brulosophy.com/2015/01/05/the-gelatin-effect-exbeeriment-results/). I thought it was well written and it allayed my concerns about flavor and mouthfeel.